An adaptor layer for Pthread, C11, and C++11 threads compatibility
As my next spare-time project, I'm considering writing a suite of compatibility header and associated library, that eases the transition from Single Unix Specification v4 to v5 and C11/C17 to C2X. C++ will not be my concern, but it adds to the discussion.
As we know, when a POSIX thread exits, it returns a pointer to a thread that joins with it, where as C11 thread returns an int. This is the issue that's stalled my thinking. I thought of the following option:

Make users use POSIX thread regardless of platform and version of standard conformance, as Pthread had existed longer, and has wider support even on non-POSIX platforms. This solution is the one I prefer the most so far, but I worry the extra feature of POSIX real-time facilities on the function prototypes may hamper the portability of my compatibility layer (because C11 threads don't have them).

Contract to int, since on ILP32 platforms, it's same as pointers. On systems that runs executables of foreign architecture (e.g. through qemu-user, or mixed 32-bit and 64-bit apps on Windows), pointer may be 32-bit anyway, so when 2 processes of different pointer width share memory (e.g. through mmap), some conflict has to occur.

Similar to 2, but ignore thread exit value anyway, as C++ does this.


What can I do to maximize portability and adoptability of my potential library with regard to difference in thread exit value type?

You can create a custom wrapper around threads, and make the choice of implementation for example dependent on some compilation flag. With pthread as default choice.

Treat return from threads as booleans - success/failure indications and alike. It's a shame C++ has no return status, but it may be workable using exceptions (I'm not C++ programmer, so I'm not sure). Rust threads return Result<> on join, which is on par with Pthread in terms of design consideration.

This isn't an answer to the question you asked "What can I do to maximize portability and adoptability of my potential library with regard to difference in thread exit value type?"

@PhilipKendall I've edited since.
